# npm ERR! This package has been marked as private

Tags: node.js, npm

I try to publish my angular library on npm.

But i get error

`npm ERR! This package has been marked as private. Remove the 'private' field from the package.json to publish it.`

But i don't have any private field in my package.json file

My package.json file of my library looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "@myfirst_mylastname/testlib123",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "peerDependencies": {
    "@angular/common": "^11.1.2",
    "@angular/core": "^11.1.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "tslib": "^2.0.0"
  },
  "description": "Test library",
  "author": {"name":"test name"},
  "keywords": ["test library"],
}
```

*what i tried*

I thought that private is always by default and i added
"private":"false" to my package.json file but i get same error on npm publish.

I `googled` and i found answers where they say - make private field true or false in the package.json file. I tried that but without success

Why is that ? How can be solved ?

Comment: Try removing the `@` from the `name` value. Package with a `@` are considered *scoped* packages in npm. https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v7/using-npm/scope

Comment: Thanks, but when i remove @ i get - String does not match the pattern of "^(?:@[a-z0-9-*~][a-z0-9-*._~]*/)?[a-z0-9-~][a-z0-9-._~]*$".-

Answer (score 4):

In case this is a problem for anyone else, the error thrown by NPM when publishing a scoped package is misleading.

There may be no "private" field in your `package.json` file, however scoped packages have their access property set to `restricted` by default, whereas normal packages are `public` by default (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-publish#access).

To be able to publish your scoped package, ensure first that your terminal is in the root of the package - the publish command only affects the directory that you are in.
Then use a flag to set its access property when publishing:

```
npm publish --access=public
```

You should also be able to set the default access value for your package using the command

```
npm access public @myfirst_mylastname/testlib123
```

which would allow you to publish without specifying the flag. (https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-access#details)

Answer (score 2):

For me it happened because I was running the command on a wrong repository

Answer (score 2):

In my case I wanted to publish a **private** package to GitHub Packages rather then npmjs.com, but the errors were very misleading. What I had to do:

1. Delete the `.npmrc` file if it exists
2. Create the file on the go:
   `echo //npm.pkg.github.com/:_authToken=\${PERSONAL_CLASSIC_GITHUB_TOKEN} > .npmrc` (while `PERSONAL_CLASSIC_GITHUB_TOKEN` is set as environment variable and the secret is written explicitly to the file - **DO NOT COMMIT with the secret** by mistake)
3. Run `npm publish --access restricted`

Answer (score 0):

You can also get this error if you run `npm publish` at the host project root (where the terminal will often put you by default) instead of inside the folder the library builds to.

So **not** here: <s>`/documents/web-projects/my-host-project/> npm publish`</s>

But here: `/documents/web-projects/my-host-project/dist/my-library> npm publish`

*Hope this helps someone...*